# async-await not working when exporting Google distance Matrix from a class

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, ecmascript-6, google-api, async-await

I'm using the google places autocomplete and the Distance Matrix to put two locations in and print out the distance between the two. I have two javascript es6 classes to separate the Google API's as services.

My problem is I'm trying to await the response on getting the distance from the distance matrix service then log it to the console, but I get undefined when I log it. the distance matrix service is returning the response after I log it.  This must mean that my await in the method is not working. What am I doing wrong?

distanceMatrix.js

```
export default class DistanceMatrixService {
    constructor(pickup, dropoff, garage){
        .....
        }

    getDistance(arg1, arg2) {
        this.distance.getDistanceMatrix({
        origins: [arg1],
        destinations: [arg2],
        travelMode: 'DRIVING',
        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL
      }, response => {
          console.log(response) //actually returns desired response
          return response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text}
    );
 }
```

main.js

```
calcButton.addEventListener('click', async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const distanceMatrix = new DistanceMatrixService(pickupInfo.formatted_address, dropoffInfo.formatted_address)
    const pickup =  pickupInfo.formatted_address
    const dropoff = dropoffInfo.formatted_address

    const ptd = await distanceMatrix.getDistance(pickup, dropoff);

    console.log(ptd) // undefined
 });
```

I expect the console.log(ptd) to wait for distanceMatrix.getDistance() to finish, but the actual results is ptd is logged as undefined then console.log(response) from the distance matrix is logged out next. This should be the other way around.

Comment: `this.distance.getDistanceMatrix` is not returning a promise, you need to wrap it in a promise and then resolve it in the response function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) works with promises and will not work with a callback. Try the following instead by returning a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) from `getDistance()` and resolving the respective value from within the callback:

```
export default class DistanceMatrixService {
  constructor(pickup, dropoff, garage) { /* ... */ }

  getDistance(arg1, arg2) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.distance.getDistanceMatrix({
        origins: [arg1],
        destinations: [arg2],
        travelMode: 'DRIVING',
        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL
      }, response => {
        console.log(response) //actually returns desired response
        resolve(response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text);
      }
      );
    });
  }
}
```

You should consider using `catch()` as well to handle errors as necessary.

Hopefully that helps!